# Expected minimum distance for $n$ points on a circle

Tags: probability

Consider $n$ points chosen uniformly and independently on a circle of circumference $1$. What is the expected minimum (arc) distance between any pair of points? Clearly this is at most $1/n$.

This problem comes under the heading [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).  We could therefore 
answer the question exactly if we were looking for the minimum of $n$ samples from $[0,1]$ but I don't know how to answer my question above.

Comment: what have you tried? Where you get stuck?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3511155/413376

Comment: @NCh Is it simply $1/n^2$?

Comment: Yes, sure.  You can also look at this more general answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3260895/

Comment: @NCh If you increase the dimension so you have points on a sphere, do you get the same $1/n^2$ dependence?

Comment: I do not know. How does it connected to a question?

Comment: @fomin Do you want the straight line distance or the arc length distance? (the answers will be different)

Comment: @almagest Arc length distance.

Comment: @fomin Then please amend the question accordingly. At  moment many readers will take it to be straight line distance.

Comment: @NCh It's the natural extension to 3d I believe. I may ask a separate question in this case.

Comment: about the uniform distribution in the circle take [a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly/50746409#50746409)